# Why does unique command act like intersect command?

Tags: r, unique, intersect

I have checked the questions but I couldn't find any explanation.

So I have two vectors and I only want to choose the different elements that one has and the other hasn't.

I defined to vectors hypothetically like:

```
hypo1=c("a01","a02","a03","a04","b01","b02","b03","b04","c01","c02","c03","c04")
hypo2=c("a03","a04","b01","b02","c02","c03")
```

And then wanted to see the duplicates in these two vectors.

```
intersect(hypo1,hypo2)
[1] "a03" "a04" "b01" "b02" "c02" "c03"
```

which seems like working fine.

However, when I wanted to see the unique elements which `hypo1` has and `hypo2` hasn't, I got the all elements restored in the first vector. such as:

```
unique(hypo1,hypo2)
 [1] "a01" "a02" "a03" "a04" "b01" "b02" "b03" "b04" "c01" "c02" "c03" "c04"
```

Then I've changed the order of the vectors I've created and it gave the intersect command result, like

```
unique(hypo2,hypo1)
[1] "a03" "a04" "b01" "b02" "c02" "c03"
```

I did some digging on the web but I couldn't find what I'm missing. I need to find unique elements which one data has and other hasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `setdiff(hypo2, hypo1)`.  `unique(hypo2, hypo1)` means something completely different:  it means you want the unique entries in `hypo2`, but will allow values to be duplicated if they are listed in `hypo1`.  This is explained on the help page `?unique`.

For example,

```
unique(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4), c(3,4))
```

gives

```
[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 4
```

because 3 and 4 have been declared to be "incomparables".  On the other hand,

```
setdiff(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4), c(3,4))
```

gives

```
[1] 1 2
```

which is what I think you were looking for.

Comment: and that's the thing that Ive completely forgotten about it since I have no repetition both in my original data and the data that I created for this question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Unique allows only one vector as argument `x`. A second vector will be used as the argument `incomparables`.  From `?unique` we learn that these values

> will never be marked as duplicated. This is intended to be used for a fairly small set of values and will not be efficient for a very large set.

One method to extract overlapping / differing values is:

```
hypo1[!hypo1 %in% hypo2]
# [1] "a01" "a02" "b03" "b04" "c01" "c04"
hypo1[hypo1 %in% hypo2]
# [1] "a03" "a04" "b01" "b02" "c02" "c03"
```

As `setdiff` has the same result as the first line, benchmarks are necessary for an appropriately sized data set to show performance differences.

Comment: Yup just reminded! Thanks for the clear explanation.